# Defining methods in parent class for multiple children

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a parent class `Person`, then it's inherited by `Employee` and `Customer`, and these are further inherited.
Also I have an array of `Person` pointers, where I store "3rd level" classes.
I would like to have `salary()` only accessible by `Employee`s, and `charge()` only by `Customer`s.
Tried to use pure functions in `Person`, but then `Employee` and `Customer` still require both defined to construct.

Maybe I could define in other way or somehow block/delete unwanted functions in children?

```
class Person {
public:
    int money;
    Person() { money = 1000; }
    virtual ~Person() {}
    void salary(int m) { if (m >= 0) money += m; }
    void charge(int m) { if (m >= 0) money -= m; }
};

class Employee : public Person {};
class Customer : public Person {};

class Programmer : public Employee {};
class Secretary  : public Employee {};
class Janitor    : public Employee {};
class Business   : public Customer {};
class Private    : public Customer {};
class Charity    : public Customer {};
```

Edit:

```
Person* people[10];
Person[0] = new Programmer();
...
```

Then I want to call a method using these pointers, e.g. `(*person[0]).salary(100)` for derived from Employee or `(*person[5]).charge(500)` for Customers.
I use casting to know if object is from E or C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done at compile time because of type erasure, but you can do it at runtime.

First, define the functions in the relevant classes instead of the base class:

```
class Person {
    // no salary or change
};

class Employee : public Person {
public:
    virtual void salary(int m)
    {
        // ...
    }
};

class Customer : public Person {
public:
    virtual void change(int m)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Then, if you already know that a `Person*` points to an employee, use `static_cast`:

```
static_cast<Employee*>(people[0])->salary(100);
```

If you do not know, use `dynamic_cast`:

```
if (auto* employee = dynamic_cast<Employee*>(people[0])) {
    employee->salary(100);
} else {
    // report error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that will work out as you requested, but I will provide a work around for you:

```
class Person {
public:
    int money;
    Person() { money = 1000; }
    virtual ~Person() {}
};
// providing the methods as specialization to the Employee and Customer classes    
class Employee : public Person {
    public:
    void salary(int m) { if (m >= 0) money += m; }
};
class Customer : public Person {
    public:
    void charge(int m) { if (m >= 0) money -= m; }
};
class Programmer : public Employee {};
class Secretary  : public Employee {};
class Janitor    : public Employee {};
class Business   : public Customer {};
class Private    : public Customer {};
class Charity    : public Customer {};
```

Now you can make sure that only Employees can access the salary method and Customers can access the charge method. But while accessing you have to write a check:

```
Person* people[10];
people[0] = new Programmer();
// while accessing you need to make sure that it is type employee!!
if (auto employee = dynamic_cast<Employee*>(people[0])) {
    employee->salary(100)
}
```

Similarly for Customer also!!!

Don't forget to include `<typeinfo>` for `dynamic_cast`!!